# how do I get a dom element from inside an iframe using php

Tags: php, dom, simple-html-dom

I am using php and simple_html_dom library. I have a page on my site that loads an iframe and the iframe changes content when certain fields are selected in the box next to it. I would like to find a dom element specifically a text field inside of a form that is not originally in the iframe when my sites page loads. what is the best way to do this? I have tried

```
$page->find("form[name='partSpecifications'] h5 text",0)->style = "width:200px;" ;
```

but it doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to interact with post loaded content inside an iframe should be with javascript but you  can't, due security policies. Refers to [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Answer (score 0):

You can't with PHP and simple_html_dom as the content loads after the php script execution has ended.  You could cURL to the page prior to it loading in the iframe and grab the content that way, but the way you describe it your setup, that wouldn't really be an option.  Otherwise Javascript would be the best way to interact with the iframe content.